# Counting strings using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to count how many strings in other nodes are contained in a different text node using XSL (ver=1.0)? I have the following xml and need to count how many colors appear in a given text. The output should be:

```
Color counts: 2 (white, gold)
Color counts: 2 (red, yellow)
```

The xml looks like:

```
<items>
    <colors>
     <color>red</color>
     <color>yellow</color>
     <color>blue</color>
     <color>white</color>
     <color>purple</color>
     <color>gold</color>
     <color>silver</color>
    </colors>
    <item>
        <text>
            Mr. Johnson prefers a white with gold logo truck.
        </text>
        <text>
            Mr. Johnson prefers a red with logo yellow truck.
        </text>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: You could use the `contains` function but if your text actually said "Mr. Johnson preferred" instead of "Mr. Johnson prefers" you would get a match on "red" which I guess is not what you want?

Comment: count() and contians(). For problem mentioned by @TimC - add space befrore and after node value you will pass to contains

Comment: No. It has to be one of the colors.

Comment: Can I use contains() for multiple strings (colors)?

Answer (score 1):

Try it along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:for-each select="item/text">
        <xsl:variable name="colors" select="../../colors/color[contains(current(), .)]" />
        <xsl:text>Color counts: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($colors)"/>
        <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$colors">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>)&#10;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank @michael. Can I use <xsl:for-each select="text>> if there are more than one <text>?

Comment: I don't know. Your example has only one and I am not sure what you want the result (or results?) to be when there are more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified the xml and results slightly to show you what I meant by multiple <text>. I tried <xsl:for-each>, but the output shows only for the first <text>.

Comment: Great! Thanks Michael.